# how to style simple_form with material design or custom css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, material-design, simple-form

I want style my simple_form in rails app with material framwork
this is my login form code

### Log in

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :login %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And this is sample input , i want sytle my form like this

https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would often prefer to ask what you have done so far, as would many other StackOverflow community members, but here's what I think you're looking for.

You can add you add your css to the `assets/stylesheets` folder and require it in your `application.css`

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="group">
    <%= f.input :login %>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <%= f.label :login %>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <%= f.input :password, required: false %>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <%= f.label :password %>
  </div>

  <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```