# How to use material design text fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design

I am looking to use material design text field in rails in order to have the field's placeholder shifting to the top when the user start typing.

I do get the field to show up properly in rails straight from the example, but I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO ADAPT IT TO RAILS `simple_form` component.

**application.html.erb**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

in my form.html.erb 
<%= f.input :title, label: false %>
<%= f.collection_select(:color, Color.all, :id, :name) %>
```

It shoudl look like this:

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If anybody has experience on this subject that would be helpful please.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) before, but looking at the docs, something like this should work.

```
<%= simple_for_form @user do |f| %>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <%= f.input_field :username, input_html: { class: 'mdl-textfield__input'} %>
    <%= f.label :username, input_html: { class: 'mdl-textfield__label'} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If you want to create the whole div with just `f.input_field` you could look into [custom inputs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs)

You might be able to do something like this inside of a custom input

```
template.content_tag(:div class: 'mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label') do
  # text_field_input_code
  # label_input_code
end
```

Comment: Hey, not sure if you tried it and it works on your end, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I get you right, you are looking for ["Float Labels"](https://dribbble.com/shots/1254439--GIF-Mobile-Form-Interaction)

This can normally be achieved with a mixture of JS and CSS, like described [here](https://codepen.io/psorowka/pen/nrcak).

In my own Rails application, where I also use `simple_form`, I have used the following code to achieve this pattern:

JS (jQuery):

```
// FLOATING LABLES:
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
    $('.form-group.string').addClass('float-labels'); // removes all labels from the form (removing with js due to old browsers & disabled JS)
    $('.form-group.string input.form-control').each( function (index, value) {
        addRemoveFloatLable($(this)); // bring back labels for already filled forms (edit).
    });
});

$(document).on('input keyup', '.form-group.string input', function () {
    if( $(this).val().length <= 1 ) { // change only needed in case first char gets added (or latest gets removed)
        addRemoveFloatLable($(this));
  }
});

function addRemoveFloatLable($element) {
  if ( $element.val() == '' ) { // input field is empty.
    $element.parents('.form-group').removeClass('show-label');  
  } else {
    $element.parents('.form-group').addClass('show-label');  
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.form-group.string.float-labels {
    label {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.form-group.string.float-labels.show-label {
    label {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
        transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, ok and how does your view look please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend this tutorial, I have followed it and it works fine for me... hope this helps,

https://www.webascender.com/blog/tutorial-using-materialize-ruby-rails-simple-form/

Also have a look at

[how to style simple_form with material design or custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287695/how-to-style-simple-form-with-material-design-or-custom-css)